# set mount option to write drive for PCManFM

Tags: permissions, automount, udev, pcmanfm, udisks

I am using PCManFM as a file manager. I set PCManFM to autodetect my drive:

I have 2 rules for `polkit`:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
   if ((action.id == "org.freedesktop.udisks2.filesystem-mount-system" &&
      subject.local && subject.active && subject.isInGroup("storage")))
      {
         return polkit.Result.YES;
      }
});
```

and

```
polkit.addAdminRule(function(action, subject) {
    return ["unix-group:wheel"];
});
```

I can successfully mount my drive. However, when I want to write something to the drive, there is always an error:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d3gu.png)

```
test.png: Error opening file “/media/Library/test.png”: Read-only file system
```

How can I fix that error? I know I can remount my drive by command but I want to set this option to default.

Comment: Is your user included in that group `wheel`?